# Setting timezone non-interactively

Tags: raspbian, script

What's the best approach for configuring the Time Zone non-interactively?

Previously for `hostname`, I've used

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_hostname
```

However, I am unable to locate the equivalent command for `timezone`?

Comment: `man timedatectl`

Comment: @JaromandaX make it an answer. Your tiny comment may be overseen (like by me).

Comment: @JaromandaX - frustrating, but not a waste of time (at least not for the community) your answer has 12 votes and it's being found be people who appreciate it. I'm sorry that it hasn't been picked up as the right / best answer.

Comment: @dlu - it's not really a big deal :p

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use `timedatectl` - for example

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Australia/Sydney
```

Answer (score 2):

The time zone is set by a symbolic link from `/etc/localtime` to a file in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` directory.

The time zone needs to be in the form 'Area/Location' where these conform to the standards used in Linux. E.g. for Area use Africa, America, Antarctica, Arctic, Asia, Atlantic, Australia, Europe, Indian, and Pacific.

For Location use the name of a specific location within the Area.
This is usually a city or small island.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones for details

For example for New Zealand use Pacific/Auckland

- First you need to remove `/etc/localtime`, otherwise `/etc/timezone` will be overwritten.
- Then create your link
- Then remove `/etc/timezone`

The commands I run are;

```
sudo rm /etc/localtime
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Auckland /etc/localtime
sudo rm /etc/timezone
```

Edit: Now I'm looking at it I don't exactly know why I'm removing `/etc/timezone`. Eeek!

Comment: This answer explains how time zones are (currently) implemented, however, the "right" answer is @JaromandaX's answer below. Use `timedatectl`, abstractions are your friend.